# What is best way to fetch related rows in each table of dataset in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dataset

Suppose I have 2 tables

```
 1. Artical(ID,Description,PubDate)
 2. ArticalMedia(ID,ArticalID,MediaURL)
```

Now I want to fetch 2 tables within `stored procedure`.

1. Table1: Top 5 Latest news
2. Table2: All Media's of Top 5 news selected in Table1

I know we can achieve this using #Temp tables. I this only & best way? Or do we have any other method to achieve same thing?

Simple 2 select statements might lead to wrong data, plesae see following example:

```
select top 5 * from Artical order by PubDate desc
```

retuns Artical's : 5,4,3,2,1

```
   select * from ArticalMedia where ArticalID in (select top 5 ID from Artical order by PubDate desc)
```

can return Medias of 6,5,4,3,2. cause new Artical might be inserted in database, after first select & before second select.

Comment: @downvoter, please comment what is wrong with question.

Comment: in your stored procedure, just select 2 time, why you need to use #temp table? also please show your stored procedure so other can help to fix. p/s: I am not the downvoter and I agree downvoter should comment with reason for down vote.

Comment: for your case, @temptable is straight forward and clean.

Comment: @ah_hau, that is my question, is there any other option than TempTables?

Comment: The stored procedure can only return at most one thing. What does it do once it obtains Table1 and Table2?

Comment: not that I can think of, cursor is not require in your case, I would suggest #temptable

Comment: It should probably be spelled _Article_, not _Artical_.

Comment: Tables returned from SP are used to bind Articals to Page with Images(Media).

Comment: We seem to be having difficulty understanding what you want. However, SO discourages inclusion of working code in questions. Why not post a complete working version of your procedure on [codereview.se] instead? Then your intentions would be unambiguous. Also include any relevant background information, ask an open-ended question about your dislike of the temp tables, and maybe even include your application-layer code (C# or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

Try this optimized query with light weight execution plan:

```
SELECT        A.*,AM.*
FROM            ArticalMedia AS AM INNER JOIN
                         Article AS A ON AM.ArticleID = A.ID
WHERE        (AM.ArticleID IN
                             (SELECT        TOP (5) ID
                               FROM            Article
                               ORDER BY PubDate DESC))
ORDER BY A.PubDate DESC
```

**Edit 2**

Create Table valued function in SQL fn_split:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split](@sText varchar(8000), @sDelim varchar(20) = ' ')
RETURNS @retArray TABLE (idx smallint Primary Key, value varchar(8000))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @idx smallint,
    @value varchar(8000),
    @bcontinue bit,
    @iStrike smallint,
    @iDelimlength tinyint

IF @sDelim = 'Space'
    BEGIN
    SET @sDelim = ' '
    END

SET @idx = 0
SET @sText = LTrim(RTrim(@sText))
SET @iDelimlength = DATALENGTH(@sDelim)
SET @bcontinue = 1

IF NOT ((@iDelimlength = 0) or (@sDelim = 'Empty'))
    BEGIN
    WHILE @bcontinue = 1
        BEGIN

--If you can find the delimiter in the text, retrieve the first element and
--insert it with its index into the return table.

        IF CHARINDEX(@sDelim, @sText)>0
            BEGIN
            SET @value = SUBSTRING(@sText,1, CHARINDEX(@sDelim,@sText)-1)
                BEGIN
                INSERT @retArray (idx, value)
                VALUES (@idx, @value)
                END

--Trim the element and its delimiter from the front of the string.
            --Increment the index and loop.
SET @iStrike = DATALENGTH(@value) + @iDelimlength
            SET @idx = @idx + 1
            SET @sText = LTrim(Right(@sText,DATALENGTH(@sText) - @iStrike))

            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
--If you can’t find the delimiter in the text, @sText is the last value in
--@retArray.
 SET @value = @sText
                BEGIN
                INSERT @retArray (idx, value)
                VALUES (@idx, @value)
                END
            --Exit the WHILE loop.
SET @bcontinue = 0
            END
        END
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
    WHILE @bcontinue=1
        BEGIN
        --If the delimiter is an empty string, check for remaining text
        --instead of a delimiter. Insert the first character into the
        --retArray table. Trim the character from the front of the string.
--Increment the index and loop.
        IF DATALENGTH(@sText)>1
            BEGIN
            SET @value = SUBSTRING(@sText,1,1)
                BEGIN
                INSERT @retArray (idx, value)
                VALUES (@idx, @value)
                END
            SET @idx = @idx+1
            SET @sText = SUBSTRING(@sText,2,DATALENGTH(@sText)-1)

            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
            --One character remains.
            --Insert the character, and exit the WHILE loop.
            INSERT @retArray (idx, value)
            VALUES (@idx, @sText)
            SET @bcontinue = 0  
            END
    END

END

RETURN
END
```

Then the query will be:

```
DECLARE @tmp nvarchar(max);

select @tmp = stuff((select top 5 ', ', cast(id as nvarchar(max))
FROM Article
ORDER BY PubDate DESC
for xml path ('')
), 1, 2, '');

SELECT        A.*,AM.*
 FROM ArticalMedia AS AM INNER JOIN
      Article AS A ON AM.ArticleID = A.ID
    WHERE        (AM.ArticleID IN (select value from dbo.fn_split(@tmp,',')))
    ORDER BY A.PubDate DESC
```

Comment: please read question carefully, I want to fetch 2 tables not one. If artical ID 1,2,3,4,5 is selected in table1 then medias of Artical 1,2,3,4,5 only should be fetched in table2.

Comment: Updated my reply. Please check now. Is this what you want?

Comment: Updated my reply with your updated question for getting output within 2 select statements if rows inserted between 2 select statements. Hope this helps.

Comment: If it worked for you then please vote up! Or let me know if any issue!

Comment: It will take some time to see what u have done, will defiantly vote up, if correct.

Answer (score 0):

Get the `TOP 5` records and then join them to the `ArticleMedia` table:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT TOP 5 ID,Description,PubDate
    FROM Artical
    ORDER BY PubDate DESC
) DS
INNER JOIN ArticleMedia AM
    ON DS.[Id] = AM.[id]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a CTE to keep it simple:

```
with Top5Artical as (
  select top (5) Artical.ID as ArticleID
  from Artical
  order by Artical.PubDate desc
),
insert into #Table1
select Top5.ArticalID,
  Art.Description,
  Art.PubDate
from Top5Artical as Top5
inner join Artical as Art
  on Top5.ArticalID = Art.ID
order by Top5.PubDate desc;

insert into #Table2
select Top5.ArticalID,
  ArtMedia.ID,
  ArtMedia.URL
from Top5Artical as Top5
inner join ArticalMedia as ArtMedia
  on Top5.ArticalID = ArtMedia.ArticalID
order by Top5.PubDate desc;

select * from #Table1;
select * from #Table2;
```

Comment: no this will also return only 1 table, please read my comments on answer of Nirav.

Comment: There, try this. Need two tables, means you need 2 queries.

Comment: still not, please read question carefully, I need Articals in Table1 &  related ArticalMedias in Table2.